# How Can I Properly Export data from DB in which some values have special character like "\r"?

Tags: r, database, oracle, export, write.table

I have a table on my DB and one of which columns has some special characters like "\r"(enter). Maybe these were done by typist who surveyed this data. This column was originated from essay question, in my opinion.

The problem is this. Because of situation above, some cells have special characters.

With DB tool, export table into Excel file does not go wrong. But export it to delimited file like CSV is different, even in R write.table. Some character ( "\r") does something; It make another line; 69297 → 69454.

So is there a way to handle this things??

Comment: Do you have the option of connecting R to the DB? Otherwise you might want to try to import directly the Excel file as it is, without converting it to csv.

Comment: I can handle DB data directly with R through ROracle. I just want to export or write.table that table into none Excel file.